# последовательная печать нескольких пакетов документов без возможности встрять в печать из вне

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно напечатать отчёт на 10000 листов. Движок отчётов построен так, что на принтер можно послать задачу лишь после рендеринга всех листов (10000). Чтобы ускорить печать формирую отчёты пачками по 100 и отправляю их на печать последовательно. Но между пачками может как-то пользователь тоже пульнуть свой лист на принтер. Есть ли какая возможность блокировать печать чужие задач в пуле принтера?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В принципе некоторые принтеры поддерживают приоритеты печати. Думаю лучше обратиться к документации на конкретный принтер. Там есть настройка печатать немедленно или все задание целиком, а также можно зарезервировать принтер для конкретного пользователя

Comment: немедленно или целиком означает, что принтер либо сразу начинает работу, либо ждёт все 100 листов. Т.е. даже сказав ему, что жди работу целиком - он 100 и подождёт, не кучу по 100 (

Answer (score 1):

Очередь печати в windows так построена, что обеспечение правильной последовательности печати считается делом оператора. К примеру, начавший печатать отчеты пользователь может громко крикнуть на весь офис: "ПРИНТЕР ЗАНЯ-Я-ЯТ!" :)

Можете также поискать подходящие настройки в свойствах очереди печати или в свойствах самого принтера. Где-то там я видел галочку "приостановить печать" - этой галочкой оператор может воспользоваться чтобы управлять очередью печати вручную. К сожалению, я сейчас не могу проверить как она работает.

Многие сетевые принтеры также могут быть обучены задерживать печать документа пока к нему не подойдет оператор и не разрешит ее вручную.

Comment: Фразу "ПРИНТЕР ЗАНЯ-Я-ЯТ!" можно записать в звуковой файл, попросить юзера врубить колонки погромче, и воспроизвести с максимальной громкостью на весь офис. Автоматизация прежде всего!

Comment: ) всё ясно-понятно. Благодарствую всем ответившим)